# Get custom field from other post in carousel

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Im using a plugin called [wp carousel](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-carousel/) to display custom post types in a carousel in the footer in the singular view of posts. By default the plugin gets the featured image and the title of the post, but i want to add a custom field (plain text) I've added to the custom post type through [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

I've tried adding this to `plugins/wp-carousel/themes/default/theme-jcarousel.php`

```
<?php global $post;
$sidans_id = $post->post_id;
$hamta_kund = get_field('kund');
echo $hamta_kund;
?>
```

on line 192 (right after the code that gets the `title`.

What this does is get the currently viewed posts' custom field, I want to get the custom field that is associated with each post in the carousel.
So every item in the carousel gets the same value (the value from the one im currently viewing).

Do anyone know what im doing wrong?

This is some documentation from the plugin-author.
http://sumolari.com/proyecto/wp-carousel/wp-carousel-documentacion-docs/

I've tried the support forum but no answer and im running out of time with the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `get_post_meta($sidans_id, 'kund', true);` instead. The `get_field` call is using the ID from the post loop and not from global.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, for page-id I had to use `$item['ID']` to get the current Id from the plugin.